# using where clause in REPLACE statment

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I am using a where clause in my PHP script, [the SQL documentation doesnt states that either I can use where clause or not.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) (I think I can't after seeing syntax)

My problem is that I have a users table that stores users registrations, 
Now I planned to store another info regarding user that is their for which type of package they are subscribed to.So I added another column `subscribed` in the `users table`,But I realized that may be adding another column could disturb the previous, insert ,select queries I wrote in PHP.
So I created another table , make the userid a foreign key here.package_id as PK,pack_detail as detail about package.
Now I want to store the package detail for the particular user,I want that If a user previous exist his row should be update, How can I do this through replace?

Comment: why dont you first select for existing row and then update ?

Comment: I know but I want to do through replace..

Comment: Replace uses `a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index` to determine when to Insert or Delete/Insert. You can either use the Primary Key in your table, or create a Unique index/key on (user) or (user,package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE works by matching the primary key.  If you specify a primary key value in the REPLACE and no row with that value exists, it works like INSERT.  If the primary key value you try to insert already exists in the table, it overwrites the other columns of the row.

So there is no need for a WHERE clause.  It's implicitly looking for `WHERE pk = value`.

If you want it to detect the package detail for a given user and you want to use REPLACE, you must make the userid the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE userpackages (
  userid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  package_detail TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(userid)
);
```

First we add the user's first package:

```
REPLACE INTO userpackages (userid, package_detail) 
VALUES (1234, 'some package');
```

Next we change the package for user 1234:

```
REPLACE INTO userpackages (userid, package_detail) 
VALUES (1234, 'some other package');
```

If userid isn't your primary key, then REPLACE isn't going to work.